# Jquery Ajax .load loops

Tags: php, jquery

i have a problem. The script below works not well. The problem is when i am clicking on a link in the lister page i get the detail, but when i am clicking once more he refresh 2 times en when i am clicking 2 times he refreshing 4 times and so on.

Can somebody help me what i do wrong?

Kr BAs

indexpage

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/admin/js/general.js"></script>

<div id="content"></div>    
<div id="contentLister"></div>
```

Javascript general.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//returns LISTER
$('ul#ajaxNav li a').click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');        
    $('#content').fadeOut().load('classes/cAjaxLister.php'+ page).fadeIn();
    return false;
});

//returns Detail
$('td ul#ajaxLister li a').click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');        
    $('#contentLister').fadeOut().load('classes/cAjaxLister.php'+ page).fadeIn();

    return false;
    });     

});
```

lister and detailpage

```
    echo '<td>
        <ul id="ajaxLister" class="actions" >
        <li><a title="View" class="view" href="?action=view&item=' . $p_UrlItem . '&id=' . $resultId[0] . '">view</a></li>
        <li><a title="Edit" class="edit" href="?action=edit&item='.$resultId[0].'">edit</a></li>
        <li><a title="Delete" class="delete" href="?action=delete&item='.$resultId[0].'">delete</a></li>
        </ul>
    </td>';
    echo '</tr>'.PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize as I may not be overly knowledgeable with javascript, but the issue seems to come from clicking on the A tag. You need to use an `event` parameter in your `click` function and then prevent the link from redirecting:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //returns LISTER
    $('ul#ajaxNav li a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var page = $(this).attr('href');        
        $('#content').fadeOut().load('classes/cAjaxLister.php'+ page).fadeIn();
        return false;
    });

    //returns Detail
    $('td ul#ajaxLister li a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var page = $(this).attr('href');        
        $('#contentLister').fadeOut().load('classes/cAjaxLister.php'+ page).fadeIn();

        return false;
        });     

    });
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/